# Unopened app taking 95%+ of battery power

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, battery, power, activity-monitor

I have a 2015 MBP on MacOS 11.6 and it recently has been running out of power quickly. When I click the battery icon on the top bar, it shows `Atom` is drawing significant power.
[image: battery dropdown]

This is weird because I have not opened Atom in the last month. To investigate, I open up Activity Monitor and I see that `Atom.app` is greyed out, has a 12 hour power of around 95, and is blank (has a `-`) for all fields.
[image]

I think I have multiple versions of Atom installed and am having trouble tracking down the app that is taking this much power. I'm also confused how it is taking this much power given that it seems to be closed any time I check Activity Monitor, yet I always see the high 12 hour energy impact attributed to Atom.

I suspect it's some Atom daemon or some old install but I'm unsure how to drill down into it further. How would I solve this?

Comment: Did you try to check file info and then opened files ?

Comment: There is some [problems](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/25394) with Mac M1 which may be related to your problem.